# Multiple tokens and multiple providers authentication in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, token, restful-authentication

I'm trying to implement a token authentication system for my RESTful API based on Ruby on Rails 4.2.4

I was thinking about making three separate models/tables:

- User table: contains the identity related info, such as name, email, profile pic...
- Authentication table: contains the information about how a user authenticates, like the provider name (email or facebook), the encrypted password or the 3rd party provider access token and other oauth stuff.
- Token table: stores all the tokens of authenticated users. I need to separate tokens from users, because each user could log in from multiple devices, and I don't want that if a user logs out from the desktop app, it also logs out the mobile app.

These are my models:

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :authentications
   has_many :tokens
end
```

models/token.rb

```
class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

models/authentication.rb

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What I'm not sure is how to structure my controllers to handle Token and Auth generation and account linking.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the tutorial from lucatironi - http://lucatironi.net/tutorial/2015/08/23/rails_api_authentication_warden/ - could be the perfect guide for you. It uses a Token Issuer service for multiple authentication sessions and independent logout.

Comment: Even if you don't use Warden, you can do the same setup with a couple manual calls for authentication and authorization. It definitely provides a great foundation, at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|`, you could send more keys into your "Authorization" header into the "options" param by separating your request values by commas. i.e.

```
Authorization: Token aaa, token2=bbb, token3=ccc
```

This would parse and give you:

```
token = aaa
options = { 'token2' => 'bbb', 'token3' => 'ccc' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you separate the token even if they will use different devices they use different sessions so logout from one doesn't logout from the other.

the would suggest you to pass to token via the header and then do a filter in application_controller which will run before any request to validate the token:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_filter :restrict_access

def restrict_access
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    @user = Token.where(token: token).first.try(:user)
  end
end

end
```

then only another filter to check if @user present otherwise send 401.

also after the user found generate a session for this End-User.

Comment: I need multiple tokens since I'm trying to avoid sessions, because it's against the stateless principle of RESTful APIs. It's the client's job to store the access token in cookies or wherever. So, if the user logs out, the server invalidates the token used to request the log out. If every device has the same token, they'd all log out at the same time